# SharePoint PDF Print and Mobile App

Tags: sharepoint-online, pdf, mobile

We have task information on a SharePoint list.The task ID has attachments coming in form on images / pdf . We need to print this information. 
Current solution: We have got the webpage,image on the page. But when we get multiple PDF, we need to merge the pdf and display it on page or get it on print.
How can we achieve this on CSOM? The SharePoint is on o365 infrastructure.

2) Get the attachment data on mobile app
We are facing issue to fetch image binary data from sharepoint and display it in base64 format. The app is built on ionic framework 3 and angular4

Please suggest.

Regards, Shripal - shripal125@gmail.com

Comment: Merging PDFs is not something CSOM provides, but there are 3rd party solutions based on Flow or REST API to do this work. Have a look at this one, it includes a free tier and comes with C#, Java, JavaScript sample code: https://github.com/Muhimbi/PDF-Converter-Services-Online. Big disclaimer, I worked on this product so consider me biased.